# Hands and chirality

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality

I was told by my teacher that human hands are the best examples of chirality as both the hands are mirror images of each other but cannot be superimposed on each other.

My question is if we join hands together as in praying position, won't the hands be superimposed on each other?

Comment: See http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18652/concept-of-non-superimposable-mirror-image-in-chirality

Answer (score 0):

In humans, chirality (also referred to as handedness or laterality) is an attribute of humans defined by their unequal distribution of fine motor skill(movement of muscles)between the left and right hands. An individual who is more dexterous with the right hand is called right-handed, and one who is more skilled with the left is said to be left-handed.  Human hands are perhaps the most universally recognized example of chirality: The left hand is a non-superimposable mirror image of the right hand; ***no matter how the two hands are oriented, *** it is impossible for all the major features of both hands to **coincide across all axes.** This difference in symmetry becomes obvious if someone attempts to shake the right hand of a person using their left hand, or if a left-handed glove is placed on a right hand.

Answer (score 0):

Super imposition means when each part of both the surface points to same direction.

Before joining your hands in prayer position, assume that a mirror is kept, the left and right hand can be joined, this is infact why we call them mirror images. But rotate either hand by 180 degrees then you will notice that the thumb of either one would be on other side. Hence they are mirror images that cannot be superimposed.

Infact they are "enantiomers" kind off and mixture of them is a racemic mixture.